# Reference list item in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having trouble having a modal fire up when a list item is clicked.
Here is the list item:

```
<div class=\"task-config-btn btn-group\">
              <a class=\"btn btn-xs default\" href=\"#\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\" data-hover=\"dropdown\" data-close-others=\"true\">
              <i class=\"fa fa-cog\"></i><i class=\"fa fa-angle-down\"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">
                <li>
                  <a href=\"#\">
                  <i class=\"complete_request\"></i> Complete </a>
                </li>
```

And here is the event:

```
$(document).on("click", ".complete_request", function ()
```

Any help is appreciated. i know i am suppose to reference the parent UL but i tried different variations and none is working.

Comment: `complete_request` is the id so `$(document).on("click", "#complete_request", function () `

Comment: Sorry, revised the code to match class not id. still the same issue.

Comment: what is the purpose of the escape character `\` in the attribute value

Comment: @ArunPJohny i am loading the code from a php function (echo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you have `id="complete_request"` but you're addressing it as by class.
Try the following instead:

```
$("#complete_request").click(function () { .... });
```

Comment: sorry was a mistake, revised code. same issue still.

Comment: Hey.... why is this `<i>` even there? Why don't you give that class/id to the `<a>` itself? Empty `<i>` isn't displayed (unless you have some tricky CSS) at all, and when you click on the link you aren't clicking on `<i>` specifically

Comment: its a dropdown menu that displays options for selections.

Comment: try giving that class/id to the `<a>` or `<li>` elements and see if it helps

Comment: That worked :) but I still think there is a better way to reference that <li>. Thanks anyway, that got me going for now until I research it further.